# How do I refer to a class instance in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two objects with inventory lists of class instances, and I  want to move those instances between them. However, I'm not sure how to actually reference a class instance that I haven't explicitly named.

In this example, multiple copies of class instances may be in an inventory, and I want to first check that a copy exists, then add it to the destination object's inventory and remove it from the source object's inventory.

How can I reference the Thing directly, or is there a better solution entirely?

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []

    def move_item(self, item, destination):
        if item in self.inventory:
            destination.add_item(item)
            self.inventory.remove(item)

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)


class Bar():

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)


class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Thing"


foo = Foo()
bar = Bar()
foo.add_item(Thing())
foo.move_item(Thing, bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference, or give your other classes a way to return a reference

For example, by saving a reference:

```
thing = Thing()
foo.add_item(thing)
foo.move_item(thing, bar)
```

An example that gets a reference:

```
foo.add_item(thing)
foo.move_item(foo.inventory[0], bar)
```

Or, if you modify `add_item` to return the item that was added:

```
class Foo():
    ...
    def add_item(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)
        return item
    ...

thing = foo.add_item(Thing())
foo.move_item(thing, bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Is there a way to give unique references to items in the inventory on-the-fly? The inventories can be of arbitrary length and order, so I won't be able to reference items explicitly by index, and I'm not sure how to save a reference without hardcoding it

Comment: @Crafty: that question is just too vague. There are many ways to do what you want. Use a dictionary instead of a list. Use a database. Require unique names and provide a search function, etc. It depends on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, how much data you have, whether the values are unique or not, etc.

Comment: Fair point! I've been struggling with this conceptually for a while. 
Context:
Foo is a character profile in a game. 
When a level is completed, an amount of loot items is generated and added to Foo's inventory. Several copies of the same item might be found, so there might be multiples copies of the class instance in the inventory at any time, in an arbitrary order.

Bar is a class that describes a single hero in the game, with squads being made of several Bars. Each Bar has its own inventory for items, that are equippable from the Foo inventory.